# Не сработал код

Tags: javascript

я скопировал код, но он не сработал.
Суть кода в том, что оранжевый шарик должен двигаться вниз на 20px в течение 10 мс.

Код html ("index.html"):

```
<!DOCUMENT html>
<html>
<head>
<meta  charset=utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="IE=edge">
<title> circle</title>
<style>
#circle{
background-color: orange;
height:100px;
left: 50px;
position: absolute;
top: 50px;
width: 100px;
border-radius: 50%;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="circle"></div>
<script scr="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Код javascript ("main.js"):

```
(function(){
 var delay = 10,
     i = 0,
     startTimer = function(){
            var elem = document.getElementById("circle"),
        bottom = elem.offsetTop;

            console.log( bottom );

             if (i < 10){
             setTimeout(startTimer, delay);

            elem.style.top = bottom + 20+"px";
    }
     i++;
    };
    var timer = setTimeout(startTimer, delay);
});
```

Comment: Вы бы еще по надписям на заборе учились программитровать

Comment: @Егор Жиляев, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 2):

Добавьте скобки для вызова вашей анонимной функции. Вот так:

```
(function(){
 var delay = 10,
     i = 0,
     startTimer = function(){
            var elem = document.getElementById("circle"),
        bottom = elem.offsetTop;

            console.log( bottom );

             if (i < 10){
             setTimeout(startTimer, delay);

            elem.style.top = bottom + 20+"px";
    }
     i++;
    };
    var timer = setTimeout(startTimer, delay);
})(); //вот в этой строке
```

Можете еще задержку сделать побольше чтобы шарик не шел камнем вниз, а падал более плавно. Например delay = 50

[Пример](http://jsfiddle.net/Lcdxoyg5/) на jsfiddle

З.Ы. не учитесь по урокам с ютуба - там вас так научат, что не переучитесь

Comment: @DreamChild, + еще `scr="main.js"` исправить на `src="main.js"`

Comment: @stck кстати да, спасибо! Я тестировал на jsfiddle, там скрипты подключаются атоматически

Comment: Спасибо огромное. Решил проблему. Насчет Ютуба - я знаю лишь какие-никакие азы о javascript, может, вы подскажете, где я могу самостоятельно обучиться и чтобы с толком?

Comment: читайте нормальные книги, пишите свой код, читайте чужой, пользуйтесь  проверенными средствами онлайн-обучения типа coursera. Уроки от сопливых школьников с ютуба - в топку

Comment: Спасибо огромное)

Answer (score -1):

script не подключился?

```
      <script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
```

Comment: @anunak - в HTML5 аттрибут `type` по умолчанию имеет значение 'text/javascript'

Comment: @stck, да и в HTML в принципе.

Comment: @0xFFh, нет, в HTML 4.01 STRICT нельзя. Так же в XHTML